# How to clear terminal after logging out?

Tags: security, tty, console

Currently on my laptop when I log out I can still see traces of my last activities (in tty). How can I tell it (Gentoo) to clear the screen before logging out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your shell is bash, add `clear_console` or `reset` to `~/.bash_logout`. If your shell is zsh, add that command to `~/.zlogout`. You might want to run this only when the shell is a login shell on a Linux console, e.g.

```
if [[ "`tty`" = /dev/tty[1-9] && $(ps -o comm= -p $PPID) = login ]]; then
  clear_console
fi
```

As the system administrator, you can configure the console to always be cleared before showing the login prompt. The easiest way to do that is to use `mingetty` instead of `getty`; you lose support for serial consoles but gain a few features such as screen clearing. First install `mingetty`. Then, assuming you use SysVinit, in `/etc/inittab`, change lines like `1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1` into

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty1
```

The Upstart equivalent would to change `exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1` to `exec /sbin/mingetty tty1` in `/etc/init/tty1.conf` (these are Ubuntu paths, you may need some adjustments for Gentoo).

Comment: One other way I use (if you have root) is to add `\e[2J\e[f` to the beginning of `/etc/issue`, so the screen gets cleared as part of drawing the login prompt. I like `clear_console` in `.bash_logout` more though

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `bash` or `zsh` (e.g. you just have `ksh`), or you want a way that works in all modern shells, this is how I do it:

**.profile**

```
test -f "$HOME"/.exitrc && trap ". $HOME/.exitrc" EXIT
```

**.exitrc**

```
type clear >/dev/null 2>&1 && clear
```

---

In my case, `.bash_profile` and `.zlogin` don't have any commands in them, that way I can just change `.profile` or `.exitrc`, rather than having to edit separate files for each shell.

**.bash_profile**

```
test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
```

**.zlogin**

```
test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to edit anything and you don't need to clear the screen every time, pressing ctrl+c works for clearing the screen back to a login prompt.