# What is the difference between `clear`, `clear_console`, `tput clear`, etc?

Tags: shell, console

I noticed this in my default bash_logout:

```
if [ "$SHLVL" = 1 ]; then
    [ -x /usr/bin/clear_console ] && /usr/bin/clear_console -q
fi
```

I was curious why it didn't just use `clear`. Googling didn't enlighten me, but it did show me `tput clear` and `tput reset`.

What are the differences between the various options for clearing the screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there a call to \`clear\_console\` in \`~/.bash\_logout\`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451069/why-is-there-a-call-to-clear-console-in-bash-logout)

Comment: I found that question while looking for an answer, but didn't see anything describing what they're doing "under the hood" and how it differs.

Comment: The links which I pointed to in my answer to that question go to some detail.  The bottom line is that one of the package maintainers decided to do it that way.

Comment: @Andrew I've added some details and links. I hope this makes it a bit more clear (sorry for the pun) than the historical and philosophical notes from the linked answers.

Answer (score 5):

On my debian system, `/usr/bin/clear` and `/usr/bin/tput` are part of the `ncurses-bin` package, and `/usr/bin/clear_console` is part of the `bash` package.

Why should the default `.bash_logout` assume that the `ncurses-bin` package is installed?

Also, if run from a Linux virtual terminal (not from a serial or pseudo tty) `clear_console(1)` will also clear the scrollback buffer (in addition to sending the `clear`/`cl` terminfo escape).

It will do that by switching back and forth to another vt [1], and by sending the `\e[3J` ["flush scrollback"](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/tty/vt/vt.c?id=964a4eacef67503a1154f7e0a75f52fbdce52022#n1518) escape.

On newer systems, `clear` and `tput clear` will also send that `\e[3J` escape (but not on many distros still in use, eg. Centos 7 or Debian 9 -- on the latter, the `TERM` environment variable should be set to `linux3.0`, which is not the default).

See the source of `clear_console` [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/bash/blob/98aa991a2f5259aff948270d5f06b2ee9a0ccc6c/debian/clear_console.c#L204).

[1] which may be defeated by the [`vgacon.scrollback_persistent=1`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/video/console/Kconfig?id=964a4eacef67503a1154f7e0a75f52fbdce52022#n50) boot param, if your kernel was compiled with the `VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK` option ("Enable Scrollback Buffer in System RAM").

Comment: That's interesting, but since [ncurses-bin](http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/ncurses/ncurses_6.1+20181013-2.dsc) is a required package, your comment about it is unfounded and should be deleted.  There's no evidence that the packager took any of that into account.

Comment: `ncurses-bin` is NOT required by `bash`. My answer is written from the perspective of a user (sufferer), the politics which led to this situation are neither relevant nor interesting.